# How should I set up these polymorphic model associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I want to have a polymorphic relationship so that many videos, tags, and users can be posted to profiles. Profiles, videos, tags, and users are all separate resources. Would I need a separate model for this and combine some sort of has_many through association with polymorphism? I want profiles to have many videos, tags and users, but also videos, tags and users to have many profiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617535/ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-association

Answer (score 1):

Why using polymorphism, when the [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) association seems to be the perfect match?

Comment: because then I would need three separate join tables?

Comment: That's correct and IMHO the way to go here, as  it is less complex and probably faster. Of course you can also go with polymorphism, then (if I understand you correctly) you will need one join table (`profilable_profile`) and a `profilable_type` column in your profiles table. Your Profile model would need a `has_and_belongs_to_many :profilables`, all others a `has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles`.

Comment: I'm slightly confused how polymorphism would work here. Could you perhaps provide the full example with the table fields so I can determine which one to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is help for you. http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Answer (score 0):

You do not need polymorphic associations for this one. Instead you need has_many and has_many through associations.

Profiles have many videos and videos have many profiles is (in plain english) :

```
Profile has many videos through profile_videos
Video has many profiles through profile_videos

ProfileVideo belongs to profile
ProfileVideo belongs to video
```

Using that, you can now do either profile.videos to get a profile videos, or video.profiles to get a video's profiles.

Comment: but what about with users? would that cause a conflict because a user already has_one profile?

Comment: ok. Then I would need several join tables... so I decided to use the `has_many_polymorphs` plugin, but now I'm experiencing this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768764/how-to-set-up-these-crud-controller-actions-for-has-many-polymorphs-and-an-error would you mind checking it out? I might just decide to go to your solution if I cant get this to work...

Comment: also if I were to have three separate join tables like this, how would I get all three queries combined into one query that is ordered by `created_at`?