# FactoryGirl and polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

#### The design

I have a User model that belongs to a profile through a polymorphic association. The reason I chose this design can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719600/designing-a-rails-application-single-table-inheritance). To summarize, there are many users of the application that have really different profiles.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, :dependent => :destroy, :polymorphic => true
end
```

---

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :profile
end
```

---

```
class Musician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :profile
end
```

After choosing this design, I'm having a hard time coming up with good tests. Using FactoryGirl and RSpec, I'm not sure how to declare the association the most efficient way.

#### First attempt

**factories.rb**

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  # ... attributes on the user
  # this creates a dependency on the artist factory
  f.association :profile, :factory => :artist 
end

Factory.define :artist do |a|
  # ... attributes for the artist profile
end
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
it "should destroy a users profile when the user is destroyed" do
  # using the class Artist seems wrong to me, what if I change my factories?
  user = Factory(:user)
  profile = user.profile
  lambda { 
    user.destroy
  }.should change(Artist, :count).by(-1)
end
```

#### Comments / other thoughts

As mentioned in the comments in the user spec, using Artist seems brittle. What if my factories change in the future?

Maybe I should use [factory_girl callbacks](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl) and define an "artist user" and "musician user"? All input is appreciated.

Comment: Love this question, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Factory_Girl callbacks would make life much easier. How about something like this?

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  #attributes for user
end

Factory.define :artist do |artist|
  #attributes for artist
  artist.after_create {|a| Factory(:user, :profile => a)}
end

Factory.define :musician do |musician|
  #attributes for musician
  musician.after_create {|m| Factory(:user, :profile => m)}
end
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks nice. I had a feeling I could utilize a callback for this purpose. Two questions regarding this solution. 1) Should I just pick a random profile factory to use (ie, Musician or Artist) when testing the user model for the :dependent => destroy option? 2) Do you recommend testing the same functionality for each profile model? ie, should I have the test "it should retrieve the associated user object" for both Musician and Artist?

Comment: 1) You could try something like 
   'user = Factory(:user)
   artist = Factory(:artist, :user => user)
   user.destroy!
   artist.reload!.valid?.should be_false'

2) IMO, less effort should be spent on testing application logic. I would restrict myself with test that Aritst 'has_one' user and likewise for user.

Answer (score 149):

Although there is an accepted answer, here is some code using the new syntax which worked for me and might be useful to someone else.

**spec/factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :musical_user, class: "User" do
    association :profile, factory: :musician
    #attributes for user
  end

  factory :artist_user, class: "User" do
    association :profile, factory: :artist
    #attributes for user
  end

  factory :artist do
    #attributes for artist
  end

  factory :musician do
    #attributes for musician
  end
end
```

**spec/models/artist_spec.rb**

```
before(:each) do
  @artist = FactoryGirl.create(:artist_user)
end
```

Which will create the artist instance as well as the user instance. So you can call:

```
@artist.profile
```

to get the Artist instance.

Comment: Thanks! To further clarify, the '#attributes for user' does not need to be a block (I was confused). It can simply be username 'user1' email 'user@test.com' etc., listed as regular attributes of the musical_user/artist_user factories.

Comment: Don't use this answer. You'll have to copy the same attributes for :musician_user and :artist_user. Not DRY. Use kuboon's or Kingsley Ijomah's answer. That said, I'm sure this answer was a helpful stepping stone for getting us to the right answer.

Comment: @Arcolye, By not DRY, I assume you're referring to there are more factories that need to be created. However, I can't see how the other 2 answers you suggested reduce the number of factories/traits. Don't you end up with the same thing?

Answer (score 40):

Use traits like this;

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        # attributes_for user
        trait :artist do
            association :profile, factory: :artist
        end
        trait :musician do
            association :profile, factory: :musician
        end
    end
end
```

now you can get user instance by `FactoryGirl.create(:user, :artist)`

Answer (score 5):

You can also solve this using nested factories (inheritance), this way you create a basic factory for each class then
nest factories that inherit from this basic parent.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        # attributes_for user
        factory :artist_profile do
            association :profile, factory: :artist
        end
        factory :musician_profile do
            association :profile, factory: :musician
        end
    end
end
```

You now have access to the nested factories as follows:

```
artist_profile = create(:artist_profile)
musician_profile = create(:musician_profile)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Nested factories can become difficult to wade through. Traits here are preferable. If you need a factory for a subclass, create a child factory that defines a parent.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that polymorphic associations in factories behave the same as regular Rails associations.

So there is another less verbose way if you don't care about attributes of model on "belongs_to" association side (User in this example):

```
# Factories
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:email) { Faker::Internet.email }

  factory :user do
    # you can predefine some user attributes with sequence
    email { generate :email }
  end

  factory :artist do
    # define association according to documentation
    user 
  end
end

# Using in specs    
describe Artist do      
  it 'created from factory' do
    # its more naturally to starts from "main" Artist model
    artist = FactoryGirl.create :artist        
    artist.user.should be_an(User)
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl associations: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Answer (score 1):

I currently use this implementation for dealing with polymorphic associations in `FactoryGirl`:

**In /spec/factories/users.rb:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    # attributes for user
  end

  # define your Artist factory elsewhere
  factory :artist_user, parent: :user do
    profile { create(:artist) }
    profile_type 'Artist'
    # optionally add attributes specific to Artists
  end

  # define your Musician factory elsewhere
  factory :musician_user, parent: :user do
    profile { create(:musician) }
    profile_type 'Musician'
    # optionally add attributes specific to Musicians
  end

end
```

Then, create the records as usual: `FactoryGirl.create(:artist_user)`