# ruby on rails, factory_girl, validates_presence_of and polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Here's the situation.

Gems: rails 3.2, factory_girl 2.5.1

```
class House
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  validates :address, :presence => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address
  attr_accessor :nested
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorhic => true
  validates :addressable, :presence => true, :unless => :nested
end
```

How this works.

```
<%= form_for @house do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
    <%= a.hidden_field :nested %>
    <%= a.label :street_address %>
    <%= a.text_field :street_address %>
```

What is the correct way to define a factory?

```
# does not work
Factory.define :house do |h|
  h.association :address
end

# does not work
Factory.define :house do |h|
  h.after_build do |record|
    Factory.build(:address, :addressable => record, :nested => '')
 end
end

# does not work
Factory.define :house do |h|
  h.after_build do |record|
    Factory.create(:address, :addressable => record, :nested => '')
  end
end
```

So basically, the 'trick' that allows accepts_nested_attributes_for :address to get around the validations and create both records at the same time is not working in factory_girl.  Currently, this ugly mess is the only solution.

```
home = House.new
home.name = 'On the prairie'
home.address_attributes = Factory.attributes_for(:address, :nested => '')
home.save
```

UPDATE
Solution:

```
Factory.define :house do |h|
  h.after_build do |record|
    record.address = Factory.build(:address, :addressable => record)
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of FactoryGirl are you using? Is this Rails3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FactoryGirl and polymorphic associations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747945/factorygirl-and-polymorphic-associations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second FactoryGirl attempt is close, but you need to do something with that built address.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :house do
    after_build do |house|
      house.address = Factory.build(:address)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Awesome. I believe it needs the nested though.

Comment: Sure, you can pass whatever attributes you want your address to have as the second argument to Factory.build.